# How to change background image and text of button on click in Android?

Tags: android, button, text

I have an idea of how to apply selectors for buttons when we need to change the background image of buttons. I also want to change the text color when the button is pressed. Is there any similar way like creating selector xml to do that? The other option is, I guess, would be changing the text color in onclick method but I wanted to know if there is some other way or some better way of doing the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> I guess, would be changing the text color in onclick method

Just create proper selector and assign it to TextView color property

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
      android:state_focused="true"
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:color="somecolor" 
    />

    <item
      android:state_focused="false"
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:color="somecolor"
    />

    <item android:color="somecolor" />

</selector>
```

And then an usage:

```
android:textColor="@drawable/yourselector"
```

> we need to change the background image of buttons

It's almost same for background just in item you'll change color property with drawable.

Answer (score 0):

You may put your codes in the setOnClickListener to your button and there you can set your desired background and text or whatever to your button. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

drawable/now_playing_next.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/icon_down" />
     <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/icon_up" />
  </selector>
```

here icon_up is normal state background image and icon_down is pressed state image

and then

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/MediaNextButton"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/now_playing_next" />
```

for changing text use OnClickListener